# Realce de sintaxe para a tag prolog

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, tag-específica

Por favor associem a tag [prolog](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog) à linguagem `lang-prolog`, para que o realce de sintaxe ocorra automaticamente nas perguntas dessa tag. Obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prolog não está entre as linguagens disponíveis para associação automática (e acho que também não é suportada pelo *Prettify*). Mas habilitei o realce como Erlang, conforme você sugeriu, pela semelhança entre a sintaxe das duas linguagens.

Comment: Estranho... [Nessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21545/215) eu usei `language-all: lang-prolog` e ele fez o realce certinho, só não posso garantir que ele tenha usado algo específico dessa linguagem (e não algo *default*, que por acaso funcionou bem).

Comment: Eu acho que ele usou o default. Se quiser, pode testar removendo o language-all.

Comment: Eu acho que não vai fazer diferença não, mas depois posso experimentar. A propósito, que eu saiba [o Prettify dá suporte a Prolog sim](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=273).

Comment: Aliás, esquece, interpretei mal o que foi postado. Pelo visto, usar `lang-erlang` pra Prolog dá um resultado melhor que o *default*, já que as duas linguagens são bastante similares.

Comment: Ok, alterei para erlang, mas não vi muita diferença no resultado.

Comment: Deu uma diferençazinha sim... [Nessa minha resposta a uma outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/64254/215) (onde eu não usei nenhuma linguagem explícita), percebi que o `is` deixou de ser realçado, e o `?-` que não era antes passou a ser. O `:-` não foi afetado (mas não era pra ser mesmo, já que esse operador não existe em Erlang).

Comment: Ficou bem melhor sim! Alterei a outra pergunta, e vi que além disso ele passou a reconhecer símbolos iniciados com `_` como variáveis (o que o *default* não fazia). Acho que pode deixar assim, então. Obrigado!

Comment: Legal. Confirmei agora que [o Prettify não suporta mesmo Prolog](https://github.com/google/code-prettify), então nem adiantaria pedir no MSE pra habilitarem esse opção.